# Can "sir" be used together with titles?

Tags: forms-of-address

In Italian, *signore* or *signor* (equivalent to *Mr.* or *sir*, depending on the context) can be used together with other titles, for example with *dottore* ("doctor"), or military ranks (e.g. *capitano*, "captain").

In particular with the military ranks, there is a difference between *Signor Capitano* and *Capitano*. When speaking with other soldiers, *Signor Capitano* would mean:

- My rank is lower than Captain
- I am speaking with somebody whose rank is higher than mine

Can *sir* be used with other titles?
What is the equivalent of *Signor Capitano*, said by someone who has a rank lower than Captain?

To be clear, I am not using *sir* as title, but as word to respectfully address a man (which is the usage *signore* has in Italian).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Sir* as a respectful term of address is employed **without** the name, or **after** the name:

> Sir, yes, sir!
>   Colonel Blimp, sir, Company A is ready to proceed.
>   Professor Knights, sir, may I ask a question?
>   Professor Knights, may I ask a question, sir?

*Sir* in this sense does not necessarily imply subordination; in formal situations it may be used to one's peers to signify either respect or distance.

> You are exactly right, sir; well said!
>   You, sir, are a liar and a blackguard.

*Sir* **before** a name or name-and-title, is always the title proper to a knight, unless the appellation is set off in apposition:

> Sir, Professor Knights, might I ask a question?

Comment: In some branches of the US military, it is so thoroughly drilled into a recruit's head that "sir" must be used when addressing an officer, that when a female officer is being addressed, one might hear, "Yes, sir, ma'am!"

Answer (score 3):

This does not happen in the American military system.

However, in the Commonwealth,  someone who is entitled to be addressed as *Sir* (or even *Lord*) who holds a military rank seems formally to have the rank first and then the *Sir* before his name.

- General Sir Peter Wall
- Major Sir Michael Parker
- General Sir David Fraser
- Colonel Sir George Everest
- Major-General Sir Isaac Brock
- General Lord George Henry Lennox
- Major-General Sir Henry Havelock, KCB
- Lieutenant-Colonel Sir Richard Fletcher
- General Lord Robert Edward Henry Somerset GCB
- Colonel Sir William John Kent, CBE, TD, DL, JR
- Colonel Sir Archibald David Stirling, DSO, OBE
- General Sir Hugh Michael Rose KCB, CBE, DSO, QGM
- Lieutenant-Colonel Lord Ninian Edward Crichton-Stuart
- General Sir David Julian Richards, GCB, CBE, DSO, ADC
- Lieutenant-Colonel Lord George Augustus Frederick Paget
- Lieutenant General The Right Honourable Sir Jerry Mateparae
- Lieutenant Colonel Sir Francis Edward Younghusband, KCSI, KCIE
- Lieutenant-General Sir Graeme Cameron Maxwell Lamb, KBE, CMG, DSO

Comment: In Italian, _signore_ is not a title: It's a way to refer to a person, in the same way _sir_ would be used from an employee of a store when addressing me. It doesn't mean that employee thinks I am a baronet. `:)`

Comment: I apologize: The question title I first used spoken of _other titles_, as if _sir_ was used as title, in my question. That clearly was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The main British authority on this kind of thing is [Debrett’s](http://www.debretts.com/). They advise that armed forces and ambassadorial ranks should precede 'Sir' and give as examples *His Excellency Sir John Brown, KCMG* and *Major Sir John Brown*.

However, in the section on academic titles they comment:

> In social usage it is not uncommon to find crown honours combined with
>   styles emanating from other sources, eg Professor Lord Johnston,
>   although this is deprecated by purists.

Comment: or Professor Sir Michael Atiyah.